# compare json files irrespective of field position in groovy using soap ui

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

Consider that I have a JSON file (named expectedResponse.json) that has some fields and values. Now I have to write a groovy script that compares the two files which will not bother even if the position of the field is jumbled...
i.e if my expectedResponse has **"name":"abc" as the 1st field** then it should not fail if my generatedResponse has **"name":abc as the 2nd field**.

Comment: Basically an identical question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410830/groovy-compare-two-json-with-unknown-nodes-names-and-values

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`JsonSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json1 = '{"name" : "abc", "value": "123", "field" : "xyz"}'
def json2 = '{"field" : "xyz", "value": "123" ,"name" : "abc"}'

def slurp1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json1)
def slurp2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json2)

assert slurp1 == slurp2
```

It converts json to an object which is `instanceof Map`, and map are equals if have same size, and keys and values despite their order.

Note that as other comments this solutions doesn't work for json arrays like

```
def json1 = '[{"n":"3","sv":"0.3"},{"n":"2","sv":"0.2"},{"n":"1","sv":"0.1"},{"n":"5","sv":"0.5"},{"n":"4","sv":"0.4"}]'    
def json2 = '[{"n":"1","sv":"0.1"},{"n":"2","sv":"0.2"},{"n":"3","sv":"0.3"},{"n":"4","sv":"0.4"},{"n":"5","sv":"0.5"}]'
```

Since the slurper for this case not convert the object to `instanceof Map`

Hope it helps,