# compare json irrespective of field value in groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON file that has same fields with different values. Now I have to write a groovy script that compares the two files which will ignore fields value.

e.g

```
json1 = '{"name" : "abc", "value": "123", "field" : "xyz"}'
json2 = '{"name" : "efg", "value": "567", "field" : "xyz"}'
```

assert should return true

```
json1 = '{"value": "123", "field" : "xyz"}'
json2 = '{"name" : "efg", "value": "567", "field" : "xyz"}'
```

assert should return false

I have try with the following code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429067/compare-json-files-irrespective-of-field-position-in-groovy-using-soap-ui)) and always return false for both case

```
def slurp1 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json1)
def slurp2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json2)

assert slurp1 == slurp2
```

Comment: If the field positions in the json are consistent use:
assert json1 == json2
as in just do a text compare. Why do anything complicated ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat the values are allowed to be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
slurp1.keySet() == slurp2.keySet()
```

Comment: using keySet() always return true for both scenario. Scenario 2 should return false in my case

Comment: No worries :-)  Have fun!